# Extra '0's from itermonthdays iterator in calendar package... is this a bug?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm seeing extra zeros from the iterator created by a call to calendar.Calendar().itermonthdays().

Is this a bug, or am I not setting up the Calendar object correctly?

See example below:

```
import calendar

day = calendar.Calendar()

for i in day.itermonthdays(2016,2):
  print(i)

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Where are they coming from? I'm just calling the iterator

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, sorry, was re-typing. It was 2016.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so itermonthdays is supposed to return a generator that returns consecutive day numbers for that month and year. It seems that it takes too many iterations to return the StopIteration exception or something like that.

Comment: The docs say "Return an iterator for the month month in the year year similar to itermonthdates().", and the itermonthdates docs say "This iterator will return ... all days before the start of the month or after the end of the month that are required to get a complete week".

Comment: I wonder why this module is even in the standard library. It's highly specialized towards the task of producing little ASCII *calendars*, with 7 columns and blank spaces for days not in the month, like the Unix `cal` program the documentation refers to. It'd never be approved for inclusion if it was proposed now, but it's curious that anyone ever wrote this and proposed its inclusion even in the early days of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zeros are the rest of the days in the week, we can see if we  call `itermonthdays2` what is happening a little more clearly:

```
for i in day.itermonthdays2(2016, 2):
  print(i)
```

Snipped outout:

```
(27, 5)
(28, 6)
(29, 0) # ends on Sunday/0
(0, 1) # we get the rest of the week even though it is March
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(0, 5)
(0, 6)
```

If we use April:

```
for i in day.itermonthdays2(2016, 4):
  print(i)
```

It starts like:

```
(0, 0) 
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3) 
(1, 4) # April starts here but not a Sunday so we get the days from March above
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
(4, 0)
```

So unless the Month starts on a Sunday and ends on a Saturday you will see part of the previous/next months days.

Comment: Thanks. Helped a ton!